# Sample size calculation for longitudinal single-group design (mixed model)

Tags: r, mixed-model, sample-size, statistical-power

I've been working the last days on figuring out how to simulate the required power for a longitudinal single-group study with 6 assessment points. The outcome of interest is continuous. Since the questionnaire is new and hasn't been validated yet, I do not have any prior information based on the literature.

I tried to conduct the simulation with the r package simr but I'm reaching my limits of statistical knowledge. I also saw other r packages such as longpower and powerlmm that can handle simulations. However, I'm not sure they were built for single-group designs.

Could you please steer me in the right direction? Apart from a suitable package I'm also wondering how one is supposed to guess suitable parameters without prior knowledge stemming from data or the literature.

Thank you in advance!

**Edit:**

My simr code:

```
library(simr)
library(lme4)
library(Matrix)
simrOptions(progress=FALSE)

follow_up <- rep(1:6) #assessment points 
ID <- 1:4000 #up to 4000 participants
X <- expand.grid(follow_up=follow_up,ID=ID) #creates a matrix with all assessment points 
b <- c(2, -0.1) # fixed intercept and slope 
V1 <- 0.5 # random intercept variance 
V2 <- matrix(c(0.5,0.05,0.05,0.1), 2) # random intercept and slope variance-covariance matrix  
s <- 1 # residual variance  
model1 <- makeLmer(y ~ follow_up + (1|ID), fixef=b, VarCorr=V1, sigma=s, data=X)
```

Output:

```
REML criterion at convergence: 73715.13
Random effects:
 Groups   Name        Std.Dev.
 ID       (Intercept) 0.7071  
 Residual             1.0000  
Number of obs: 24000, groups:  ID, 4000
Fixed Effects:
(Intercept)    follow_up  
        2.0         -0.1
```

Does this look correct so far?

Simulate power:

```
powerSim(model1, nsim=20)
print(model1)
plot(model1)
```

The simulation takes way too long. I experimented last night and changed the code to nsim=1 and it still took 1.5 hours to complete. However, the output stated that my power was between 0 and 97%.

I'd appreciate any feedback! :)

Comment: Could you say a tiny bit more about your study and its goals? By "longitudinal single-group" do you mean that you will be getting six sets of answers to the survey from each participant, but that there are no explicit 'treatment' groups? What are you interested in finding out? Average values, temporal slopes?

Comment: Hi! In most (all?) power calculations, you need to specify the expected effect size. You mention that you are going to use a questionnaire, so likely self-reports? Even if your questionnaire is new, and the concept it's designed to measure has not been studied before, you can make a guess based on previous research, in this case based on previous, related self-report research. An alternative would be to simply check the power to detect both a small and moderate effect (by conventional standards).

Comment: And if you are going to use multilevel regression, simr is a very good package to conduct power analyses. Roughly, you do it by generating a dataset that mimics the one you intend to collect, specify the parameters, run a simulated model, and then use powerSim and/or powerCurve to estimate power. But please specify how are you planning to analyze the data (esp. are you going to use a multilevel regression) and what kind of effect are you interested in.

Comment: Thank you for all the responses so far!
My study will be a single-group study and therefore not have a control group. It'll last two years and within those two years participants will fill out self-report assessments at six timepoints. I'm interested in finding out average values and expect a small effect size. Usually I'd use a Cohen's d of about .30 but in simr you can only choose slope as effect size. The primary continuous outcome measure I'm using is a 10-item scale that produces an outcome from 10 to 50. Do I have to simulate the scores for simr and if yes what is the best practice?

Comment: I've added an edit above with my simr code. I'm planning to use a mixed model (see above for model) because I want to account for the correlation between timepoints of each participant.

Comment: Your code looks correct to me, but as you said, it tests the power to detect your fixed slope (-0.1). The huge CI for the power estimate is likely due to low number of simulations. By average values, do you mean you want to investigate mean-level change in y between time points? If so, this is in my experience not typically done with regression models, but via repeated measure ANOVAs or latent difference score models, in which case you would have to use a power analysis suitable for those. Sorry I can't provide a better answer!